# Python string split on multiple characters

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA': ['apple:50-100(+)', 'peach:75-125(-)', 'banana:100-150(+)']})
```

New to regular expressions...if I want to split `'apple:50-100(+)'` (and other example strings above) into a `DataFrame` as below, what's the best way to do that?

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? How many strings? Where are the strings? What format to they follow?

Comment: Many strings in the format, `'apple:50-100(+)'` and `'peach:50-100(-)'`. They are in a column in a DataFrame.

Comment: Ah, well that's important information! Could you post an example of the column?

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: Can you share more about the first part of the string? Is it always just a single word, letters a-z?

Comment: Your solution solves my issue.

Comment: Of course, I just always want to make it better ;)

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.

Comment: I miss the part where you explain what you tried so far.

Comment: various failed attempts at str.split()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can update the regex if you provide more details on the format.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA': ['apple:50-100(+)', 'peach:75-125(-)', 'banana:100-150(+)']})

pattern = r"(.*):(\d+)-(\d+)\(([+-])\)"

new_df = df['columnA'].str.extract(pattern)
```

`df`:

```
             columnA
0    apple:50-100(+)
1    peach:75-125(-)
2  banana:100-150(+)
```

`new_df`:

```
        0    1    2  3
0   apple   50  100  +
1   peach   75  125  -
2  banana  100  150  +
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for pandas, TipsyHyena take a look at the other pandas .str accessors here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#string-handling

Comment: Do you mind directing me to the documentation for this notation here `r"(.*):(\d+)-(\d+)\(([+-])\)"`? Not familiar with regex.

Comment: Best resource to get started with regex imo is https://regexone.com/. Others may have better recommendations

Comment: @TipsyHyena I really like Regex101, it's how I wrote the solution for this, [here](https://regex101.com/r/HGLvkE/1). https://www.regular-expressions.info is also nice as a reference/guide.

Answer (score 1):

[`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) can be used to split on any string that matches a pattern. For the example you have given the following should work

```
re.split(r'[\:\-\(\)]+', your_string)
```

It splits the string on all colons, hyphens and parenthesis (":", "-", "(" and ")")

This results in an empty string as the last member of the list, you can either slice this off

```
re.split(r'[\:\-\(\)]+', your_string)[:-1]
```

Or filter out empty values

```
filter(None, re.split(r'[\:\-\(\)]+', your_string))
```

Comment: assuming the split is by : - +

Comment: Using re.split on the example string yields `['apple', ':', '50', '-', '100', '(', '+', ')', '']`. Now how can I transform this list into a DataFrame as in the question? `pd.DataFrame(re.split('(\:|\-|\(|\))', 'apple:50-100(+)'))` isn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative:

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:16:48) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> split_it = re.compile(r'(\w+):(\d+)[-](\d+)\((.)\)')
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(split_it.findall('apple:50-100(+)'))
>>> df
       0   1    2  3
0  apple  50  100  +
>>>
```

Comment: Can this function take a dataframe column as input?

Comment: Probably yes but it would be better if you edit your post and show us a real sample of your data though.